# If entry id then show certain content

Tags: expressionengine

I've been trying to make something visible only on certain entry_id in expressionengine

{if entry_id="33"}
    ... show certain content
{/if}

is this even possible in eemcs?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's referred to as a simple conditional in EE, and it's fast enough.

One very important thing to remember in EE is that the standard if:else/else:if routine of an advanced conditional can be very slow, primarily because EE renders all of the code segments and then works its if:else magic. If you find yourself testing many ids or groups, this slows the site down proportionally. In fact, sometimes EEs parse order can stop if:else from functioning entirely.

Instead, consider [Mark Croxton's Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee), a fantastic free plugin that lets you have as many conditions, even nested conditions, without slowdown. It parses just the conditions, then when triggered, is smart enough to descend and run the right code segment:

Answer (score 2):

Sure - but you need to use the {entry_id} variable within a tag pair that provides that variable. For example within a {exp:channel:entires} tag pair.

If you're using url_titles in the URI you may want to think about using segment variables instead. For example:

```
{if segment_2 == "blog-post"} You're on a blog post{if}
```

Comment: What Phil said. Let us know if you need additional help!